# Find node dependency versions within unexpected directory structure

Tags: npm

I have the following directory structure for a project I'm working on:

```
application
  package.json
  client
    package.json
  server
    package.json
```

Additionally, some of the dependencies used in the project have a similar `client`/`server` hierarchy with a base-level `package.json`. The reasoning here is beside the point. What I'm trying to do is find the installed version(s) of a given lib within this project wherever it may be getting pulled in. I had hoped `npm ls` would do this, but it appears to only inspect the base-level `package.json` files.

I'm considering writing a bash script or something that recursively finds all `node_modules` directories starting in the root directory and then using `npm ls` in each directory, but am also hoping to find an easier answer. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining an alias as follows:

`alias npm-ls-lib='_npm-ls-lib(){ \find . -type d -name "$1" -exec npm --prefix {} ls . \; | grep -v \(empty\); }; _npm-ls-lib'`

and now I can call it like this: `npm-ls-lib lib-name`